# Getting stats on my questions I've asked on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange overall

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-close, statistics, vote-to-reopen

I would like to see stats on my questions, in particular, to see how many of them were:

1. voted for closure with at least one close vote, or
2. closed, or
3. downvoted, or
4. closed and then reopened.

Is it possible to get this information? Are particular [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) required?

Comment: You can do all of those except 1 with some caveats (unsuccessful close votes aren't shown) using SEDE / API.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. voted for closure with at least one close vote

Not possible via the site.

You can examine *individual* questions by checking the timeline. And even then you can only see if they were in the "Close votes" review queue, however, a question might end in the queue without an actual close vote. Or might have had a close vote. An expired close vote and no close vote would look the same in the timeline.

This information also [cannot reliably be found in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/let-sede-users-get-hold-of-data-on-unsuccessful-close-votes-for-stats) because expired votes are removed. The only option provided by regular Stack Exchange tools is to check for any *current* close votes (as of last Sunday for SEDE) but no way to check if it ever had a close vote.

> 2. closed

No special privileges needed. You can search for `user:me closed:yes` ([link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+closed%3Ayes)). If you prefer to see all non-duplicates, then `user:me closed:yes duplicate:no` ([link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano)).

> 3. downvoted

Not easily possible on the site. You can search in SEDE for all of your questions which have downvotes.

This information can be found in SEDE.

This query can give breakdowns of votes to all questions by a user:

```sql
SELECT PostId as [Post Link]
  , SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Upvotes
  , SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Downvotes
  , SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId in (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Total
FROM Votes
WHERE PostId in (
  SELECT Id 
  FROM Posts 
  WHERE OwnerUserId = ##PosterUserId:int## 
    AND PostTypeId = 1
)
GROUP BY PostId
```

[See and run on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1809266)

> 4. closed and then reopened

Similar to 1. you can individually examine your question timelines and there would be a closure event and a reopen event.

For checking in bulk, you can search in SEDE.

Comment: Going off the search for 2, can't you use `user:me score:..-1` for 3 as well?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it won't find a post with, say, +1 / -1. Only where the total score is negative.

Comment: BTW there's a caveat for 1 (with SEDE) you [can't get data about unsuccessful / expired close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/let-sede-users-get-hold-of-data-on-unsuccessful-close-votes-for-stats)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat OK, I should have checked that. It'd be the same for reopen votes, right? I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 3):

VLAZ has already covered what is, and isn't, possible in their [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427495/2029983), however, if you want the following queries would work in a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1809263?UserId=4561887) for non-deleted questions.

```sql
SELECT VT.Name AS VoteType,
       COUNT(*) AS Votes,
       COUNT(DISTINCT P.Id) AS DistinctPosts
FROM dbo.Posts P
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Votes V ON P.Id = V.PostId
     LEFT JOIN dbo.VoteTypes VT On V.VoteTypeId = VT.Id
WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserID:int##
  AND P.PostTypeId = 1 --Question
GROUP BY VT.Name;

SELECT COUNT(P.ID) AS posts,
       COUNT(P.ClosedDate) AS ClosedQuestions
FROM dbo.Posts P
WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserID:int##
  AND P.PostTypeId = 1 --Question;
```